# Next.js 13 : Basic middleware example compilation fails with "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: next.js13

Setup :

- On Windows, I created a basic tutorial app in Next.js immediately after installing Next.js 13.
- To do so, I used create-next-app and chose `Typescript`, plus the `/src` folder.
- Under the `pages` folder, I've added a `/cars/cars.ts` file. It displays some *Hello world* text.
- I run the project in Visual Studio with a `launch.json` file that was added on my behalf by VSCode itself (I requested to have the `"Next.js: Debug server-side"` config).

Everything runs as expected.

Now I'm trying to add a **middleware**.

- I created file `middleware.ts` in the **same folder** as the `pages` folder.
- Inside, I copied-pasted the code from the Next.js manual :

```
    // middleware.ts
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
    import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
    
    export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
        // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-version`
        const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
        requestHeaders.set('x-version', '13');
    
        // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
        const response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
                // New request headers
                headers: requestHeaders,
            },
        });
    
        // Set a new response header `x-version`
        response.headers.set('x-version', '13');
        return response;
    }
```

Then I run the project.

**Problem :**

The project compiles properly when I hit F5.
But then the first time I hit the page, its compilation fails :

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1920 ms (165 modules)
wait  - compiling /src/middleware (client and server)...
event - compiled successfully in 303 ms (66 modules)
error - Error [TypeError]: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5724:19)    
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/formdata.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5881:49)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6094:35)    
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6510:49)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at <unknown> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:11635:30)
    at requireFn (file://C:\Users\MathieuBergounioux\source\repos\Next.js\mynext\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\edge-runtime\index.js:1:7079) {
  middleware: true
}
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 206 ms (166 modules)
error - Error [TypeError]: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5724:19)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/formdata.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5881:49)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6094:35)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6510:49)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at <unknown> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:11635:30)
    at requireFn (file://C:\Users\MathieuBergounioux\source\repos\Next.js\mynext\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\edge-runtime\index.js:1:7079) {
  middleware: true
}
```

**Troubleshooting:**

I've upgraded everything with this command but it didn't help :

```
npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest
```